# How to read Sim card information with AOSP

Tags: android, open-source, sim-card

I'm working in Android Open Source Project (AOSP). I want to read all information which stored in SIM CARD. As I see, we can get phone number, ... But i need to read Value Added Services (which also stored in SIM card : http://www.ebay.com/gds/SIM-Card-Guide-/10000000177629426/g.html). Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: you should use internal api of android . use IccFileHandler class in framework/base/telephony . for using internal api you should use reflection in java .